# I can't run a tool in debian (C/C++)

Tags: c++, server, debian

When I try to run this tool by running MAKE I get this error:

```
root@ns1:/home/teamspeak3-user/f2/Ns# make
g++ -pthread -lc++abi -lc++ -lsupc++  ntp.o checksum.o   -o ntp
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++abi
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lc++
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
<builtin>: recipe for target 'ntp' failed
make: *** [ntp] Error 1
root@ns1:/home/teamspeak3-user/f2/Ns#
```

What can it be the problem? I'm running debian server.

Comment: Question has nothing to do with C#, thus deleted the tag.

Comment: [`libc++`](http://libcxx.llvm.org/) and [`libc++abi`](http://libcxxabi.llvm.org/) are part of the standard C++ library for [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/). They should not be used when compiling with GCC. [`libsupc++`](http://libcxx.llvm.org/#libsupcxx) is another variant of a standard C++ library, meaning you are actually trying to link with *three* standard libraries (`libc++`, `libsupc++` and the GCC standard `libstdc++`).

Answer (score 0):

It would help providing you a fix if you gave us a link to the source of your tool (I guess it's something you downloaded).

As explained by Joachim Pileborg in the comments, you are linking against three different C++ standard libraries and two of them are not found. You would just need to remove them from the command line.

One option is to edit the makefile to remove references to `libc++` and `libsupc++`.

But it would be nice to understand where this strange result comes from (and maybe open an issue to the project so that they fix something). Did you run `./configure` before running make ? Or another command to generate the `Makefile` ?